# Where's the Plugin called Plugin Reloader

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

Just installed the QGIS 2.16.1 Nodebo version, while trying to sink my teeth into building plugins , I found that the plugin called "Plugin Reloader" doesn't exist !! Please help [image]

Comment: Most welcome, glad it helped! Will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others =)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's an **experimental plugin**. You can enable it by going to (from your image):

```
Settings > Show also experimental plugins
```

Now you should be able to view the incredibly useful *Plugin Reloader* plugin.